# Should ferrite beads be closer to the stepper motor or to the motor driver?

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver, ferrite-bead

Stepper motor, cable with ferrite bead, and dual H-bridge driver:

[image: Photo]

I noticed that the cable that came with these motors had the bead closer to one end. Does it matter which way it's wired as far as noise returning to the supply or EMI from the unshielded cable?

The H-bridge has a separate power supply from the MCU that toggles the H-bridge, but there is no electrical isolation anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Put the bead on the side that connects to the driver board. The bead will suppress CM noise from the board.